# Form post method return HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net, httphandlerfactory

i develop asp web project a page from mine has form tag as follow:
[Form tag](HTTP://i.stack.imgur.com/SS5wT.png)

when i clicked button to submit data i got this error :
[error 405](HTTP://i.stack.imgur.com/3fEDC.png)

i read a lot of articles and all speak about IIS handler mapping,but i just have VS2013 to development not IIS installed as a server i can config, so if anybody can help in this issue i'll be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YOUR_ACTION_IN_CONTROLLER", "YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME", FormMethod.Post))
{
enter code here
}
```

This code will be send model class to your post method in your controller.